# What do brackets around a class name mean in a C# class

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

As a beginner in the world of .NET and C# I dont know what does it mean when I see the following syntax at the beginning of a .CS file ?  I am confused about the meaning of the brackets around the names?  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
   [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "55.555.5.555")]
   [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "5.5.34444.55")]
   [System.SerializableAttribute()]
   [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
   [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You should use this syntax to add [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your class/method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called [`Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx) and provide metadata for your classes.

For example, the `SerializableAttribute` lets some classes know that your object can be written to disk or sent over a network connection to another program.

Comment: I mark your reply as an answer because in two lines you gave me a precise answer with a tangible  example in addition to a URL. Although Tim Ebenezer answered first but yours was very much to the point and immediately helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing there is what is known as an 'Attribute'. This describes something about the class, and can allow other pieces of code to interact with that class in specific ways.

You can find out more about attributes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks but cant they just use USING ?

Comment: using specifies namespaces that you want to be able to access in the file. Attributes describe the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the examples you showed, they're used to designate attributes above the declaration of the entity to which they apply:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

These are [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Attributes provide a powerful method of associating metadata, or declarative information, with code (assemblies, types, methods, properties, and so forth). After an attribute is associated with a program entity, the attribute can be queried at run time by using a technique called reflection.